# wpf listview drag select multiple items

Tags: .net, wpf

Just wondering if anyone has any idea on how to do this. I want to let the user select multiple items by clicking and dragging the mouse (without letting the click go). Say the user clicks on item 1, then drags down to item 10; item 1 through 10 should get selected as if he clicked item 1, then shift + clicked on item 10.

Let me know thanks!

Comment: I solved it, I'll post the solution later. Thanks.

Comment: I've posted a new solution to this question over at [WPF Drag & drop from ListBox with SelectionMode Multiple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553622/wpf-drag-drop-from-listbox-with-selectionmode-multiple).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok here's my solution, I created a helper class that handles the PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp for the ListView, and a small style for the ListViewItems that when the mouse is over it indicates the helper class, so it can decide if it selects the item or not (based on the mouse left button being pressed or not). Anyway, here's the full project:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DragSelectListBox.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DragSelectListBox"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="local:DragSelectionHelper.IsDragSelecting" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ListBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="local:DragSelectionHelper.IsDragSelecting" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
        <ListBox Margin="8"
                 local:DragSelectionHelper.IsDragSelectionEnabled="true">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 2" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 3" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 4" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 5" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 6" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 7" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 8" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 9" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 10" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 11" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 12" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 13" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 14" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 15" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 16" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 17" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 18" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 19" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 20" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 21" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 22" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 23" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 24" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 25" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 26" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 27" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 28" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 29" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Item 30" />
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DragSelectListBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    // CARLO 20100519: Helper class for DragSelection
    public class DragSelectionHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        #region Random Static Properties

        // need a static reference to the listbox otherwise it can't be accessed
            // (this only happened in the project I'm working on, if you're using a regular ListBox, with regular ListBoxItems you can get the ListBox from the ListBoxItems)
        public static ListBox ListBox { get; private set; }

        #endregion Random Static Properties

        #region IsDragSelectionEnabledProperty

        public static bool GetIsDragSelectionEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsDragSelectionEnabledProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsDragSelectionEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsDragSelectionEnabledProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragSelectionEnabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragSelectingEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(DragSelectionHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsDragSelectingEnabledPropertyChanged));

        public static void IsDragSelectingEnabledPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox listBox = o as ListBox;

            bool isDragSelectionEnabled = DragSelectionHelper.GetIsDragSelectionEnabled(listBox);

            // if DragSelection is enabled
            if (isDragSelectionEnabled)
            {
                // set the listbox's selection mode to multiple ( didn't work with extended )
                listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;

                // set the static listbox property
                DragSelectionHelper.ListBox = listBox;

                // and subscribe to the required events to handle the drag selection and the attached properties
                listBox.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(DragSelectionHelper.listBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
                listBox.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(listBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown);
                listBox.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(DragSelectionHelper.listBox_MouseLeftButtonUp);
            }
            else // is selection is disabled
            {
                // set selection mode to the default
                listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single;

                // dereference the listbox
                DragSelectionHelper.ListBox = null;

                // unsuscribe from the events
                listBox.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(DragSelectionHelper.listBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
                listBox.MouseLeftButtonUp -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(DragSelectionHelper.listBox_MouseLeftButtonUp);
                listBox.MouseLeftButtonUp -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(DragSelectionHelper.listBox_MouseLeftButtonUp);
            }
        }

        static void listBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // to prevent the listbox from selecting / deselecting wells on right click
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private static void listBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // notify the helper class that the listbox has initiated the drag click
            DragSelectionHelper.SetIsDragClickStarted(DragSelectionHelper.ListBox, true);
        }

        private static void listBox_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // notify the helper class that the list box has terminated the drag click
            DragSelectionHelper.SetIsDragClickStarted(DragSelectionHelper.ListBox, false);
        }

        #endregion IsDragSelectionEnabledProperty

        #region IsDragSelectinProperty

        public static bool GetIsDragSelecting(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsDragSelectingProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsDragSelecting(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsDragSelectingProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragSelectingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragSelecting", typeof(bool), typeof(DragSelectionHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsDragSelectingPropertyChanged));

        public static void IsDragSelectingPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBoxItem item = o as ListBoxItem;

            bool clickInitiated = DragSelectionHelper.GetIsDragClickStarted(DragSelectionHelper.ListBox);

            // this is where the item.Parent was null, it was supposed to be the ListBox, I guess it's null because items are not
            // really ListBoxItems but are wells
            if (clickInitiated)
            {
                bool isDragSelecting = DragSelectionHelper.GetIsDragSelecting(item);

                if (isDragSelecting)
                {
                    // using the ListBox static reference because could not get to it through the item.Parent property
                    DragSelectionHelper.ListBox.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion IsDragSelectinProperty

        #region IsDragClickStartedProperty

        public static bool GetIsDragClickStarted(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsDragClickStartedProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsDragClickStarted(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsDragClickStartedProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragClickStartedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragClickStarted", typeof(bool), typeof(DragSelectionHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsDragClickStartedPropertyChanged));

        public static void IsDragClickStartedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isDragClickStarted = DragSelectionHelper.GetIsDragClickStarted(DragSelectionHelper.ListBox);

            // if click has been drag click has started, clear the current selected items and start drag selection operation again
            if (isDragClickStarted)
                DragSelectionHelper.ListBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
        }

        #endregion IsDragClickInitiatedProperty
    }
}
```

So as you can see, all you need to do is add the style in your xaml, and set the:

local:DragSelectionHelper.IsDragSelectionEnabled="true"

Attached property to the ListView, and that'll take care of everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Based on Carlo's answer, I modified some of his code, now you can use CTRL to continue to select without clearing current selection, and use SHIFT to select items like the 'Extended' mode.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SteamFriendsManager.Utility
{
    public class DragSelectionHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        #region IsDragSelectionEnabledProperty

        public static bool GetIsDragSelectionEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool) obj.GetValue(IsDragSelectionEnabledProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsDragSelectionEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsDragSelectionEnabledProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragSelectionEnabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragSelectingEnabled", typeof (bool), typeof (DragSelectionHelper),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsDragSelectingEnabledPropertyChanged));

        private static void IsDragSelectingEnabledPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listBox = o as ListBox;

            if (listBox == null)
                return;

            // if DragSelection is enabled
            if (GetIsDragSelectionEnabled(listBox))
            {
                // set the listbox's selection mode to multiple ( didn't work with extended )
                listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;

                // and subscribe to the required events to handle the drag selection and the attached properties
                listBox.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown += listBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown;

                listBox.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += listBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
                listBox.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += listBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;

                listBox.PreviewKeyDown += listBox_PreviewKeyDown;
                listBox.PreviewKeyUp += listBox_PreviewKeyUp;
            }
            else // is selection is disabled
            {
                // set selection mode to the default
                listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Extended;

                // unsuscribe from the events
                listBox.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown -= listBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown;

                listBox.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= listBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
                listBox.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp -= listBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;

                listBox.PreviewKeyDown -= listBox_PreviewKeyDown;
                listBox.PreviewKeyUp += listBox_PreviewKeyUp;
            }
        }

        private static void listBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var listBox = sender as ListBox;
            if (listBox == null)
                return;

            if (e.Key == Key.LeftShift || e.Key == Key.RightShift)
            {
                SetIsDragSelectionEnabled(listBox, false);
            }
        }

        private static void listBox_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var listBox = sender as ListBox;
            if (listBox == null)
                return;

            if (e.Key == Key.LeftShift || e.Key == Key.RightShift)
            {
                SetIsDragSelectionEnabled(listBox, true);
            }
        }

        private static void listBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // to prevent the listbox from selecting / deselecting wells on right click
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private static void listBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            SetIsDragClickStarted(sender as DependencyObject, true);
        }

        private static void listBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            SetIsDragClickStarted(sender as DependencyObject, false);
        }

        public static DependencyObject GetParent(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;

            var ce = obj as ContentElement;
            if (ce == null) return VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);

            var parent = ContentOperations.GetParent(ce);
            if (parent != null)
                return parent;

            var fce = ce as FrameworkContentElement;
            return fce != null ? fce.Parent : null;
        }

        #endregion IsDragSelectionEnabledProperty

        #region IsDragSelectingProperty

        public static bool GetIsDragSelecting(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool) obj.GetValue(IsDragSelectingProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsDragSelecting(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsDragSelectingProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragSelectingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragSelecting", typeof (bool), typeof (DragSelectionHelper),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsDragSelectingPropertyChanged));

        private static void IsDragSelectingPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listBoxItem = o as ListBoxItem;

            if (listBoxItem == null)
                return;

            if (!GetIsDragClickStarted(listBoxItem)) return;

            if (GetIsDragSelecting(listBoxItem))
            {
                listBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }

        #endregion IsDragSelectingProperty

        #region IsDragClickStartedProperty

        public static bool GetIsDragClickStarted(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool) obj.GetValue(IsDragClickStartedProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsDragClickStarted(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsDragClickStartedProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragClickStartedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragClickStarted", typeof (bool), typeof (DragSelectionHelper),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, IsDragClickStartedPropertyChanged) {Inherits = true});

        private static void IsDragClickStartedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listBox = obj as ListBox;

            if (listBox == null)
                return;

            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
                return;

            var hitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(listBox, Mouse.GetPosition(listBox));
            if (hitTestResult == null)
                return;

            var element = hitTestResult.VisualHit;
            while (element != null)
            {
                var scrollBar = element as ScrollBar;
                if (scrollBar != null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
            }

            if (GetIsDragClickStarted(listBox))
                listBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
        }

        #endregion IsDragClickInitiatedProperty
    }
}
```

Demo:
[image: Demo]

Comment: Thanks! It was nearly a copy and paste except for the changed namespace that generated errors (and the small section "public partial class Window1 : Window" at the start)

Answer (score 2):

Also note that with `SelectionMode=Extended` this is possible already, if the user holds down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key prior to mouse button down.