# In UWP, how to implement multiple selection in GridView like we select in windows explorer?

Tags: xaml, uwp

Girdview has selection methods Single/Multiple/Extended. To select multiple items, I need to tick the checkboxes in each Griditem, which takes more time if select more than 20 or 30 items. It would be great if I am able to select gridview items using mouse by click & drag a selection rectangle, like we select in Windows explorer.

As far as I know there is no such default option to do that. My idea is to draw a rectangle shape, and find which griditems are under that area. But, how it could be implemented?

[image]

Comment: nothing, probably you have to implement it on your own

Comment: I think this answer will help you a lot
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890625/win-rt-xaml-gridview-drag-select-multiple-items

Comment: I already tried with that. could not implement my desired functionality with it.

Comment: Is it necessary to draw a rectangle on the xaml to point out which item is selected?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT , Extremely sorry for late reply. It is not necessary to draw any rectangle on xaml to point out selected items. I am not mentioning that. I want to multi-select gridview items by mouse click-drag selection as shown in image. To achieve that, I suggested a way, by drawing a rectangle and selecting the GridView items under that rectangle, since, as far as I know, there is no obvious way to multi-select GridView items except by clicking each item individually.