# WPF Is it legal to invoke another event from within an event-invocation-method

Tags: .net, wpf, events, event-handling

The following code was part of an answer I have received to solve a [probem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767708/wpf-drag-and-drop-from-a-listbox-that-has-selectionmodeextended) I have posted in SO. It works fine, however I'm curious if its allowed to manually invoke another event from within an 
invocation-method with the EventArgs of the original event:

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp( MouseButtonEventArgs e )   {   
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown( e );   
}
```

I have seen this pattern frequently but never used it because I feared always that this could lead to sideeffects or problems in future versions of WPF. Has anyone the insight to tell me if such redirected event-invocations are save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be very careful with doing this. If the event data contains stuff that is only relevant to the original event the other event handler can be confused by this data. Especially when it comes to events from external devices like the mouse.

Maybe this example you posted is ok, I don't know. But I can definitely see a problem with doing the other way around, raising mouse down when you get a mouse up - the mouse down handler could (potentially, I have no idea if it does this) query the input device for the actual status of that mouse and they wouldn't match. Or perhaps do some operation on the mouse that only works when it is pressed etc.

So in summary: It may work, but I would not rely on it unless you are 100% sure it won't break under certain conditions

Answer (score 2):

It would be much better if there were a new event or method that both OnMouseLeftButtonDown and OnMouseLeftButtonUp could call, with an appropriate name clarifying your intention.  As the code stands right now, the control is basically lying, which works only as long as your clients never call your bluff and rely on you being truthful.  It's the kind of the thing that, with more complex code, can lead to very frustrating debugging sessions.  It's much better to structure and name your code so that you're expressing your intention, rather than lying to achieve a convenient side effect.

Comment: +1 I agree totaly with your answer. However the main question is not answered. This is my fault, I should have exlpained the question more exactly. The question is if it could confuse the internal state of WPF-mouse-handling if events are invoked from foreign invocation-methods. I fear that this could be true, I have seen WPF already a lot of times doing weird things due to special code in events. But I don't know and am looking for an answer for this. But perhaps this answer will me only be given by reflector and for each case separately (And never for a future releases of .net).

Comment: @HCL, I don't think you can safely assume it will work, as directly calling the event invocations is not in the spirit of the original usage contract.  My understanding is that the physical action event invocations are exposed as protected virtual so that they can be overridden, but not with the intention that they be manually invoked.  The only exception I could see is if you were trying to emulate user interaction at an event level and even then you'd want to preserve the sequence in a way that's consistent with what's normally possible.

Comment: I think there is a general rule to understand here. Your question implies you did some looking and can't find anyone authorative who said you can do this. In general if you are doing something tricky (with someone else's code) and can't find a document that says its legal, then they didn't test for your scenerio.  You're living dangerously, and eventually you're going to get bit!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you would not be able to do this, you're just calling a method on the base class.  There's a WndProc() somewhere that receives the actual windows messages and translates them into the same call you're making.