# WPF override DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid with some styling, properties and events.
I want to override its OnMouseLeftButtonDown and OnMouseLeftButtonUp events to do something.
How do I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need an override rather than just a subscription? What do you need this for? What have you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: @H.B. I am trying to solve the problem asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767708/wpf-drag-and-drop-from-a-listbox-that-has-selectionmode-extended and am trying the solution given. Apparently it doesn't solve it (even when I did what ChrisF suggested). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own class based on `DataGrid` and add the event handlers you need. Then in your XAML use your `DataGrid` rather than the "normal" one.

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    // Your overrides here
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MyNamespaceMyClass"
        ....
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.MyNamespace">

    ....
    <local:MyDataGrid ... />
    ....

</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to solve the problem asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767708/wpf-drag-and-drop-from-a-listbox-that-has-selectionmode-extended and am trying the solution given. Apparently it doesn't solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Brilliant - helps me use ComponentModel attributes as grid column headings by overidding OnAutoGeneratingColumn within MyDataGrid.cs

Answer (score 0):

Add an event and in the event put `e.Handled = true` if you want to mark it as handled.  Be aware ordering of event bubbling is different for down compared to up and there is a preview.  Or you can override the method. I am just more comfortable with events.  If you override the down event then the up event might not fire - not sure but it is something to test for.